# How to cope a data to a scope as a backup field in Angularjs to roll back when request failed?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a block of data, then when i edit one of them, i want to copy the current date of the item to a scope like `$scope.backup_field` to be able to roll back when the update failed. As my code below, the `$scope.backup_field` can get the item's data which i'm editing, but when the updated failed, i console log out the `$scope.backup_field` is also modify following the newest data that i modified.

My code:

```
$scope.block_data = [
   [
     {id: 1, name: 'Data 1'},
     {id: 2, name: 'Data 2'}
   ],
   [
     {id: 3, name: 'Data 3'}
   ]
];
$scope.backup_field = [[],[],[],[],[],[]];

$scope.editItem = function(_no, index){// _no has value from 0 to 6 
   $scope.backup_field[_no][index] = $scope.block_data[_no][index];
}

$scope.updateItem = function(_no, index){
   $http.post(.....).then(function (response){
       var res = response.data;
       if (res.status === 200){
           //Do something if update successfully
       }else {
          alert('Failed');
          $scope.block_data[_no][index] = $scope.backup_field[_no][index]; //The problem is here, the $scope.backup_field[_no][index] value also change following the data of item that user modified in UI.
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: did you use your `$scope.editItem` on `onchange`?

Comment: No, i did not. I just using ng-click to execute the function.

Comment: can you show your HTML code please. I need to know how you call those functions. I think I've figured out your problem but I want to be sure by looking at your html code

Comment: I do follow piedpiper and it solve my problem. Thanks for reading my post :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `angular.copy` for that -

> Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.
>   This functions is used internally, mostly in the change-detection
>   code. It is not intended as an all-purpose copy function, and has
>   several limitations (see below).

```
$scope.block_data[_no][index] = angular.copy($scope.backup_field[_no][index]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your idea save my time...=D